# Efficient structure for traversing multiple data types by one key

Tags: python, algorithm, memory-management, data-structures, iteration

I am using an algorithm which uses one key to look up data.  In my latest implementation the data (per key) is 1.)  A set of values, 2) A second set of values, 3.) A tuple (or some other structure) with a couple numerical values in it.

So, each entry contains 1,2,and 3.   However, for any given key, there may be many entries.  Perhaps millions (or perhaps just one).

The algorithm loops, and after each loop, all the data needs to be updated and changed.  Everything.  So depending on implementation, it is likely I need to recreate most of the structures (it proves very difficult to simply re-use my old structures).

In my last version of this algorithm I used a dictionary of lists of tuples.  But in that version, I was not using actual sets, instead I was using sequences to represent the sets.  So each list entry was just a single tuple.

I am thinking about a dictionary of adjacency list, where each sublist is: set1, set2, tuple of values.  But I am worried that this just isn't very efficient, and I am worried about the overhead of recreating these structures over and over.

I am also considering the recordclass:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/recordclass
I have no experience with it, however.  Is it a good fit here?  Would it be reasonable to use a dictionary of lists of recordclasses?  Where each recordclass holds my values and my two sets?

Or is there another structure I am not thinking of?  Thank you for any advice.  I know it can be hard without knowing exactly what the project is, but just assume the general plan of using many instances of (set1, set2, tuple of values) - which each correspond to some key, is necessary.

*Edit* - Updating with more information:

A given dictionary key would be a number, and the value would be some sort of collections that correspond to that number, that have the following fields:  2 intbitsets, and 2 numeric values (one of which matches the key).

Example (note, I don't necessarily want to use a dictionary of lists of lists

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {64: [[set([1,2,3,7,8,9]), set([5, 7, 4]), (64, 
13)], [set([7,9,11,12,18,21]), set([35,19,8]), (8, 64)]], 121: 
[[set([9,8,7,5,6,2]), set([1,2,3]), (121, 120)]] }
```

My dictionaries (or.. any alternate implementation) could have thousands of keys, and each key could have any amount of (set1,set2,number1,number2) that matches to it.  I will need to do many iterations of accessing these fields, and after each iteration the values will likely change, and there may be more or less of them.

A likely change would be creating a new field that comes from union of various sets, and then changing the 2 numbers based on the outcome of that union.  There could be any number of unions done.  Also, at the end of every round of changes, I no longer need any of the old entries.

Comment: What do you mean by, "for any given key, there may be many entries?" When you say, "entry," to me that means one `key -> value` pair. Could you please add some detailed examples of one and also many (like two) entries? Also, could you please provide some details on the kinds of updates and changes the data undergoes?

Comment: Apologies.  When I say "entry", I mean a collection of (two sets, and two values) that are all related.  A given key, however, may map to many such collections, in a single list or whatever structure (and I guess the actual entry would be the list).

Updating the main post with your requests right now.

Comment: You could use a class to hold all of your data in whatever format you need and then have a dictionary of these classes. The class could then have some kind of update function.

Comment: @MartinEvans that makes sense, but I worry about performance.  Do you know if the speed and memory-use of such an implementation could be competitive?